# Obtaining Calls for Entire Month

Tags: go, twilio, twilio-api

I want to page through an entire month's worth of Calls usage in a report. Unfortunately, I'm experiencing random 500 errors from the API.

First I initialize the first page call to /Calls.json

```
// Set initial baseUrl
urlStr := "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + accountSid + "/Calls.json"
baseUrl, err := url.Parse(urlStr)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Build query parameters and URL
v := url.Values{}
v.Set("StartTime>", "2017-08-01")
v.Set("StartTime<", "2017-08-02")
v.Set("To", os.Args[1])
v.Set("PageSize", "1000")
v.Set("Page", "0")
baseUrl.RawQuery = v.Encode()

// Begin recursive call
pageNext(baseUrl)
```

I then determine if there is a "next page" by checking the response property `next_page_uri`, if the property is not blank then I proceed to recursively call the API with the previous calls `next_page_uri` query.

Each time I end up with a 500 error, sometimes within the first call and sometimes it is after 100-ish calls.

Is this really the best way to obtain such a report?

Comment: Seems like you need Twilio tech support, not Stack Overflow...

Comment: Did you code in a retry mechanism? You will have to be able to handle connectivity issues potentially, and 500 return codes may be resolved by a retry.

Comment: No. 500 status code is way too broad to trust a retry this early. I honestly think their hypermedia `next_page_uri` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Adrian I have a ticket open, but I thought stackoverflow was a place to ask about previous experiences with the API.